# Zend Framework 2 DateFormat Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2, date-formatting, view-helpers

How do I get a 4-digit year number with:

```
echo $this->dateFormat(
new DateTime(),
IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, // date
IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // time
"nl_NL");
```

Now I get: `01-01-14` (1st of January 2014)
But I want: `01-01-2014`

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790274/zend-framework-2-formatting-a-date-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but you can maybe use something like:

```
$dateString = Zend_Locale_Format::getDate(
    date('d-m-Y'),
    array(
        'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
    )
);
```

Or just use `date()`.